# azure-data-factory-utilities validation fails

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

The node module `@microsoft/azure-data-factory-utilities` systematically fails to validate Data Factories.

Here is the command line is use: `npm run start validate ../etl-dataplatform subscriptions/xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/DataPlatform-STAG/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/etl-dataplatform-stag`

Error logs:

```
ERROR === CmdApiApp: Failed to run resource validation. Error: {"stack":"TypeError: Cannot read property 'concept' of undefined\n    at Function.<anonymous> (/Users/gt/Local/azure-datafactory-deploy/downloads/main.js:1271:27040)\n    at /Users/gt/Local/azure-datafactory-deploy/downloads/main.js:16:2243\n    at Object.next (/Users/gt/Local/azure-datafactory-deploy/downloads/main.js:16:2348)\n    at o (/Users/gt/Local/azure-datafactory-deploy/downloads/main.js:16:1087)","message":"Cannot read property 'concept' of undefined"}


=====ERROR=====
Error: Command failed: node  /Users/gt/Local/azure-datafactory-deploy/downloads/main.js validate ../etl-dataplatform subscriptions/xxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxx/resourceGroups/DataPlatform-STAG/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/etl-dataplatform-stag

Execution finished....
```

However, when I click on the "validate" button in the Azure Data Factory interface, the validation is successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is due to the ADF resource ID being incorrect. You seem to be missing a `/` at the beginning of your resource ID, before 'subscriptions'.

The correct command would be `npm run start validate ../etl-dataplatform /subscriptions/xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/DataPlatform-STAG/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/etl-dataplatform-stag`